# HTML input adding prompt using jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, prompt, html-input

I found a tutorial on best way to add prompt to input fields. [Here](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/input-prompt-text/)
I did everything it says and still it doesn't work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text][title],input[type=password][title],textarea[title]').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('input-prompt-' + i);
    var promptSpan = $('<span class="input-prompt"/>');
    $(promptSpan).attr('id', 'input-prompt-' + i);
    $(promptSpan).append($(this).attr('title'));
    $(promptSpan).click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).focus();
    });
    if($(this).val() != ''){
        $(promptSpan).hide();
    }
    $(this).before(promptSpan);
    $(this).focus(function(){
        $('#input-prompt-' + i).hide();
    });
    $(this).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $('#input-prompt-' + i).show();
        }
    });
});
```

});

Is there something wrong with this code that I wasn't able to find? I even created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9JV4/) to be sure and it doesn't work either...

Comment: Make sure you are including jquery library. In the fiddle u didnt

Comment: you're right, jsFiddle works then but my website is still dead...

Comment: Got it i think.. You are not specifying title attribute in the search box in your website.. But just value, change it to title

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the html placeholder attribute?

```
<input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First name">
```

This would add your prompt text to your element in display. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjeevi/2ygdt/) jsfiddle examle.

Comment: That is indeed right way to do it but it lacks IE support (except IE10) so I'd rather go for the jQuery sollution

Answer (score 0):

OK got it. The cause of the problem was entirely different.
I added some alerts to the script and found out it's never executed. Then I found an error in different script that's executed before this script. Error caused termination of entire JS, therefore this script was never executed. After I corrected the error, it works fine!